# Looking for a way to clone Win 10 with settings, incl/excluding specific installed software and its registry entries

Tags: windows, windows-registry, clone, exclude

as stated in the title I am looking for a way to clone my windows that allows me to chose with software i want to include or exclude from the cloning process.

I googled a lot but couldnt find a cloning software with those features.
I guess it makes sense, since the registry is so "delicate" to mess with and the OS might become obsolete in the process.

However, lets say for example, I have 200 programs installed, all licensed with registry entries and I want to spare me the hustle to reinstall and go through all the registration processes of each program as well as going through all the Windows settings that I have done on my main machine. Lets say I just want to move my OS to another SSD and exclude some of the software that I dont need anymore. And exclude some User directories to save even more disk space.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Maybe a command line tool that I don't know of yet?

Comment: Most Settings are synchronized provided you are logged into a user linked to a Microsoft Account. In order to clone your registry, requires you clone your system drive, which requires third-party software to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about cloneapp

https://github.com/builtbybel/CloneApp/releases

Now it is important to know that many apps require files in addition to registry settings.
You also need to clone all/relevant parts of c:\programdata and c:\uses<username>\appdata

Above program attempts to do this for you.
You can write your own plugins, and submit them for others to enjoy.

Comment: Thanks you! That seems nice!

Comment: Well try it out, and if you like it leave an upvote or etc.

Comment: Was gonna upvote your answer for sure! Need 15 rep though :/